# Type of an expression in haskell

Tags: haskell, types

I'm new to Haskell and I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding some of the concepts of the language.

I have the following expression:

`\f x → (f x,f 1)`

And from my understanding, I can say that:

- At first, I can't really say what f is because I have no information,
  so I say it can be anything.

  Then judging from the application of (f x) I can say that it's a
  function of type a->b where x::a

  Then judging from the application of (f 1) I can say that a is of
  type Integer, therefore x is the same type

Then I don't really understand why the whole expression is of type:

`(Integer → b) → Integer → (b, b)`

I have a little guess and I'm going to say that:

`(Integer → b)` is the type of the function f, so it receives and integer and returns a type b

`Integer` is the type of x

`(b b)` is the type of the two functions called?

Can someone point me in the right direction please?   Thank you

Comment: You've got it pretty much correct.  `\f x -> (f x, f 1)` would be constrained to `(Integer -> b) -> Integer -> (b, b)`, since in GHCi the literal `1` defaults to `Integer`.  Thus `f` which is inferred to be a function takes an `Integer`.  Since `x` is passed to `f` in one of tuple elements then `x` must be an `Integer`.  The `(b, b)` is just a tuple, where `b` is the return type of `f`.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's a great explanation! Appreciate it.

Comment: Would you please be so kind as to tell me why this `c b a = a b` is of type `c :: t1 -> (t1 -> t) -> t` ? @bheklilr

Comment: why do you think it is, using the explanation I gave for your first question? This looks like homework, and you'll do yourself a favor by figuring it out on your own :)

Comment: My guess is that t1 is the type of b, because I have no idea what b is so it can be anything, then based on the fact that b is passed as a parameter for a, then a is of type (t1 -> t), so as for the end, it's of type t as that is the return type of a, which seems to be a function. Fun part is I actually understood while explaining my guess. Thank you! @@Also, this is not homework, I just have a test tomorrow and I want to understand everything before it.

Comment: awesome! Glad I could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.

Since `f` is applied to `1 :: Integer`, then `f :: Integer -> b`.

And since `f` is also applied to `x`, then `x :: Integer`.

And since the result of the lambda is a tuple of applications of `f`, then the result type is `(b, b)`.

So the type of the lambda is a function that takes something of the type of `f` to a function that takes an `Integer` to a tuple of `(b, b)`.

Edit

```
c b a = a b
```

Assume `b :: t1`.

Since `a` is applied to `b`, we can say that `a :: t1 -> t`.

Since the `c` takes something of the type of `b` (`t1`) to something of the type of `a` (`t1 -> t`) to the result of the application of `a` to `b` (`t`), we can say that `c :: t1 -> (t1 -> t) -> t`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I appreciate it. @pat . Would you please be kind and tell me why this `c :: t1 -> (t1 -> t) -> t` is the type of `c b a = a b`? That's the only thing I don't really understand now.

Comment: No need, I already understood it on my own, sorry to bother you.

Answer (score 4):

The entire lambda takes a function `f`, and `x` as inputs; it produces
a pair; the first element of the pair is the result of applying f to x, the second element is the result of applying f to 1. From `f 1`, we know that the input to f has to be limited to the `Num` type class.

```
getPair :: Num a => (a -> b) -> a -> (b, b)
getPair =           \f          x -> (f x, f 1)
```

The only constraint is `Num a =>`

```
getPair id 8.9 => (8.9, 1.0)
getPair (\x -> x > 0) (-9.8) => (False, True)
```